# Using dot syntax in dplyr::across

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

This question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035940/how-to-convert-double-vector-to-function); it still hasn't been answered.

I am trying to calculate summary statistics across multiple columns. The function `dplyr::summarise_each` has been deprecated so I get a warning, but it allowed me to pass in the calculation for skewness:

```
summarise_each(funs(mean = mean,
                    median = median,
                    sd = sd,
                    skewness = moments::skewness(.)))
```

However, when I use `dplyr::across` and include `skewness = skewness(.)` in it, I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(...)`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

This is the working function:

```
ag_data %>%
    filter(data_year_fiscal < 2021 & data_year_fiscal > 1988) %>%
    mutate(g_k_it_to_K_int = g_k_it/K_int) %>%
    select(K_int, K_phys, Intangibles_intensity, g_k_it_to_K_int,
           # new measures
           total_q, i_phys, i_int, i_tot,
           c_tot,
           operating_activities_net_cash_flow,
           investing_activities_net_cash_flow,
           financing_activities_net_cash_flow,
           # standard measures
           tobins_q_star,
           i_phys_star,
           c_star) %>%
    select(K_int, K_phys, Intangibles_intensity, g_k_it_to_K_int,
           # new measures
           total_q, i_phys, i_int, i_tot,
           c_tot,
           operating_activities_net_cash_flow,
           investing_activities_net_cash_flow,
           financing_activities_net_cash_flow,
           # standard measures
           tobins_q_star,
           i_phys_star,
           c_star) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean = mean,
                        median = median,
                        sd = sd,
                        skewness = moments::skewness(.))) %>%
    pivot_longer(
      cols = everything(),
      names_to = c("metric", ".value"),
      names_pattern = "(.*)_([^_]+)$"
    )
```

This is the problematic function:

```
ag_data %>%
  filter(data_year_fiscal < 2021 & data_year_fiscal > 1988) %>%
  mutate(g_k_it_to_K_int = g_k_it/K_int) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c(
    K_int, K_phys, Intangibles_intensity, g_k_it_to_K_int,
    # new measures
    total_q, i_phys, i_int, i_tot,
    c_tot,
    operating_activities_net_cash_flow,
    investing_activities_net_cash_flow,
    financing_activities_net_cash_flow,
    # standard measures
    tobins_q_star,
    i_phys_star,
    c_star
  ),
   .fns = list(
     mean = mean,
     median = median,
     sd = sd,
     skewness = moments::skewness(.)
     ),
   .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))  %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = c("metric", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_([^_]+)$"
  )
```

The data:

```
structure(list(K_int = c(11.85294, 16.859952, 20.3777616, 23.88320928, 
27.189167424, 30.5188339392, 4.5886, 5.63738, 6.653804, 7.9427432, 
9.94269456, 11.550355648, 22.5039845184, 23.47018761472, 23.837550091776, 
24.5622400734208, 639.19194, 927.419652, 1206.4772216, 1465.55267728, 
1750.485841824, 2048.8569734592, 2322.22127876736, 2584.04762301389, 
2881.76689841111, 3204.21311872889, 3729.00919498311, 7035.77875598649, 
8657.05820478919, 9907.84656383135), K_phys = c(25.927, 25.943, 
23.465, 24.516, 32.156, 36.745, 29.592, 30.947, 23.892, 24.28, 
25.529, 27.102, 29.979, 31.359, 31.111, 37.441, 1477.894, 1745.221, 
1959.444, 2166.205, 2727.27, 3109.172, 3496.257, 4063.378, 4622.655, 
5205.636, 6102.889, 13999.479, 15248, 15035), Intangibles_intensity = c(0.313736337326105, 
0.393896944304215, 0.464791925880873, 0.493462798985628, 0.458153015724821, 
0.453718323085569, 0.134245741736541, 0.154092538946949, 0.217830376964378, 
0.246494941498339, 0.280299395992544, 0.298826693855014, 0.428786295689993, 
0.428060101485417, 0.43381581592166, 0.39614446026265, 0.30192063908374, 
0.347004993471902, 0.381082515057108, 0.403538123275236, 0.390929274319465, 
0.397217034646695, 0.399111445898415, 0.388729076421362, 0.384009179843854, 
0.381007206371045, 0.379276628076346, 0.334475519035851, 0.362143364413763, 
0.39722196656569), g_k_it_to_K_int = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0884801464498976, 
0.0872391075286747, 0.0976043177707068, 0.0889556645870157, 0.0911464789078264, 
0.0953211583740837, 0.060957854946904, 0.0669545435680467, 0.0742588291391029, 
0.0961687061288879, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    total_q = c(0.0240471530658863, -0.0085391306655672, 0.0629693454346635, 
    1.66047909037245, 0.425325280821302, 0.137633397590273, -0.070555373515971, 
    0.0176373086000091, -0.128454631608322, -0.0928497918823993, 
    -0.0388020650570239, -0.0472448566040888, 0.0809952985526135, 
    0.00230944512418794, -0.0717967078914873, 0.767288531110069, 
    1.00664636930138, 1.226411413576, 1.38539170528803, 1.27369366600044, 
    1.38779172413936, 1.24355704146002, 1.18524890350901, 1.17589072346115, 
    1.13474100540682, 1.33294840867422, 1.57820945455047, 0.699618417835253, 
    0.521082186593649, 0.548471080275074), i_phys = c(0.0424278211532994, 
    0.0517205691697763, 0.0495526570223474, 0.103757150188276, 
    0.173184647532324, 0.0329934194306133, 0.0531255533911811, 
    0.0696008847123807, 0.0403724212355109, 0.0434102176521528, 
    0.0533474133263738, 0.0540994735042621, 0.0416533474611995, 
    0.0290760903558181, 0.0340876836099288, 0.0872998467109318, 
    0.214076329348485, 0.139884259965375, 0.0953581244860897, 
    0.08480943814019, 0.0911844978181534, 0.0972643474510191, 
    0.0917495815620865, 0.11280114293716, 0.101288835435623, 
    0.0898207762203129, 0.0992137894771306, 0.186840828044513, 
    0.0841919799863629, 0.062204408257918), i_int = c(0.218846950539408, 
    0.195278234957493, 0.160965533405266, 0.172913377792333, 
    0.166998596056402, 0.147737387567876, 0.0628942157541414, 
    0.0565554729876012, 0.0570762713485919, 0.0841915963318562, 
    0.110173735922024, 0.100519584537153, 0.110878106344387, 
    0.0828725736524215, 0.0711628271317389, 0.0828411303373278, 
    0.249586380024823, 0.195695929093932, 0.173879829169043, 
    0.157997140480711, 0.15941694117478, 0.144819932775935, 0.132441229685815, 
    0.124545553885529, 0.122563657903796, 0.11953640295596, 0.120770216642545, 
    0.26365921906339, 0.123079071815186, 0.113247998679109), 
    i_tot = c(0.261274771692708, 0.24699880412727, 0.210518190427613, 
    0.27667052798061, 0.340183243588727, 0.18073080699849, 0.116019769145323, 
    0.126156357699982, 0.0974486925841029, 0.127601813984009, 
    0.163521149248398, 0.154619058041415, 0.152531453805586, 
    0.11194866400824, 0.105250510741668, 0.17014097704826, 0.463662709373308, 
    0.335580189059307, 0.269237953655133, 0.242806578620901, 
    0.250601438992933, 0.242084280226954, 0.224190811247902, 
    0.237346696822689, 0.223852493339419, 0.209357179176273, 
    0.219984006119675, 0.450500047107903, 0.207271051801548, 
    0.175452406937027), c_tot = c(0.235017949030377, 0.0356887808715419, 
    0.207435692753154, 0.296188002901715, 0.180867004445408, 
    0.0717539470328953, 0.132632934623372, 0.118083649789647, 
    0.119003520081521, 0.155706819830311, 0.160044412357791, 
    0.174192974895756, 0.0943795000030938, 0.108922540371076, 
    0.087093393277233, 0.191968668552344, 0.341438953625522, 
    0.280888724810104, 0.255497801206086, 0.23431112086393, 0.23509651961126, 
    0.221183969154638, 0.217531346910507, 0.210308754518412, 
    0.204354743781864, 0.196356913290281, 0.196615835392053, 
    0.320768620408342, 0.17010963409667, 0.143151293365787), 
    operating_activities_net_cash_flow = c(-1.059, -0.176, 3.53, 
    7.191, 1.831, 2.618, 4.257, 4.593, 1.43, 2.134, -0.869, 0.396, 
    3.466, 5.082, 6.092, 7.263, 237.889, 291.86, 371.001, 408.02, 
    500.65, 584.515, 608.132, 793.464, 656.951, 864.672, 825.446, 
    1396.753, 1780, 2092), investing_activities_net_cash_flow = c(1.039, 
    -1.678, 0.235, -4.243, -8.178, -1.863, -1.502, -1.869, -1.447, 
    -1.208, -1.462, -1.883, -16.634, -1.168, -1.509, -4.793, 
    -320.051, -299.68, -263.264, -260.422, -756.775, -418.371, 
    -460.466, -665.71, -670.858, -646.132, -1055.687, -1476.338, 
    -1549, -1159), financing_activities_net_cash_flow = c(0.047, 
    1.802, -3.836, 0.102, 3.044, -0.734, -2.636, -1.993, 0.076, 
    -0.892, 1.708, 0.63, 13.12, -3.676, -2.461, -4.871, -37.578, 
    -30.113, -128.012, -136.627, 261.262, -143.222, -159.905, 
    -108.865, 35.659, -201.322, 202.804, 194.361, -419, -905), 
    tobins_q_star = c(0.0350406911713658, -0.0140885788073855, 
    0.117653952695504, 3.27809899657367, 0.784954596342829, 0.251945842971833, 
    -0.0814958434712084, 0.0208501631822148, -0.164228612087728, 
    -0.123223846787479, -0.0539141760350973, -0.0673797136742676, 
    0.141795089896261, 0.00403791574986449, -0.126808042171579, 
    1.27064915467001, 1.44202282098716, 1.87813291267983, 2.23841099822194, 
    2.13541504612906, 2.27853952853953, 2.06302618510652, 1.97249372686276, 
    1.92368175567225, 1.84213947396031, 2.15341506782264, 2.5425326738697, 
    1.05122867429566, 0.816926810073452, 0.909905553708015), 
    i_phys_star = c(0.0523374571241377, 0.0753654491456782, 0.081756157730409, 
    0.1938632005114, 0.341899167890357, 0.060890658042045, 0.0592034445640474, 
    0.0803933495539335, 0.0477267586518887, 0.0554997488699146, 
    0.0707990115321252, 0.0751694151748991, 0.0594052099476053, 
    0.0509022982754595, 0.0596001147995791, 0.154189836392273, 
    0.274087283221257, 0.200384466003651, 0.146031935210498, 
    0.13702866731583, 0.152875651196447, 0.159693026359693, 0.152209977447372, 
    0.187723900159513, 0.16570203412038, 0.145815121396687, 0.16028262444781, 
    0.301004983049831, 0.12650470778234, 0.0975209863588667), 
    c_star = c(0.100936524453694, -0.14718247386894, 0.156342751416567, 
    0.32725335606222, 0.126284875183554, -0.0584338848115437, 
    0.0987441693577323, 0.0906663963233306, 0.0934500920929331, 
    0.123723422065964, 0.11004942339374, 0.144267303850523, 0.0239096745627629, 
    0.0891290570065713, 0.0651806498931726, 0.236636559416284, 
    0.213466656230432, 0.206139276565166, 0.204874339696806, 
    0.199886294275315, 0.207062120159449, 0.196709530042863, 
    0.207076996705232, 0.204907991603592, 0.19395685067941, 0.182927127375934, 
    0.181062986347874, 0.219432960356972, 0.126147551633886, 
    0.100144281217209)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You have two options.  You can simply list the `skewness()` function the same way you did with `mean()`, `median()`, and `sd()`; as a `function` object like so: `.fns = list(mean = mean, median = median, sd = sd, skewness = moments::skewness)`.  Alternatively, if you insist on complicating things with `.` as a placeholder for the "current column", then you must state it as a [formula](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts) preceded by [`~`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/tilde.html): `skewness = ~ moments::skewness(.)`.

Comment: @akrun I edited the title because it was unclear. It quoted an error message with confusing wording, but if you think the previous title was better, feel free to roll it back. Your answer indeed got at the issue, which was the dot syntax, but the question has been asked & answered regardless of the title.

Comment: I think this a specific question to a specific task raised by the OP. It is not 1:1 a duplicate. Therefore I vote to reopen this question.

Comment: It seems to me that the crux of the issue is how to update the use of `.` from `summarise_each` / `summarise_all` to `summarise(across)`. The missing piece was that the newer syntax needs the whole formula notation, i.e. `~fun(.)`, not just `fun(.)`. Totally fine with you guys disagreeing with that assessment. I think that gets muddled by both the unclear error message and the excess code in the question (e.g. `select` calls, pivoting) that isn't what triggers the error